# Should async or non-async methods be used in SignalR Hub?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, async-await, signalr

I have the following `Hub` class in `SignalR` part and here I defined all of the methods related to connection:

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    // here I cannot call this, and need to convert this method async
     await AddToGroup("stockGroup");
    //

    string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
    _connections.Add(name, Context.ConnectionId);
    return base.OnConnected();
}

public async Task AddToGroup(string groupName)
{
    await Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
    await Clients.Group(groupName).SendAsync("Send", $"{Context.ConnectionId} joined");
}
```

I have a look at many different examples regarding to these connection methods (and other Hub methods) and see that some of them use `async` method while some of them not. In this example above, I need to convert `OnConnected()` method to `async` in order to call `AddToGroup()` method. Of course the reverse situation would also be ok, but I am not sure which one is better. So, should I use `async` methods or non-async methods for all of the methods in the `Hub`? Any help would be appreciated.

**Update 1 :** Converted method (to async).

```
public override async Task OnConnected()
{        
    await AddToGroup("stockGroup");

    string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
    _connections.Add(name, Context.ConnectionId);
    return base.OnConnected();
}
```

**Update 2:**

```
public override async Task OnConnected()
{
    // #1 There is no async method in "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR" library. 
    //await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, "SignalR Users");  

    // #2 I just have sync version of "AddToGroupAsync()" and used it
    await Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, "SignalR Users");

    /* #3 I think there is no need to use this custom method in the Hub. 
    Because the same method is already exist in the IGroupManager interface */
    //await AddToGroup("jiraGroup");        
    
    string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
    _connections.Add(name, Context.ConnectionId);

    // #4 Here also the same problem and I used sync version of OnConnected()
    //await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    await base.OnConnected();
}
```

Comment: Sounds kind of opinion based ... It depends on what you need. Do you need to wait until the end of the execution or not? You stated that 'there is some problems I see that async call in the Hub may cause not being able to connect to the hub sometimes', What problems? Do you had them in your use case? Would it be critical in your use case if that happens?

Comment: @nilsK Sorry, you are right. I get a little bit cleaner. The question may seem to be opinion based, but as this is the first time I use SignalR and encountered this issue when building my Hub class, I wanted to to select the best option for general case (what would you prefer in Hub methods? async or sync?). Of course both of them is possible, but what is the pros and cons of these 2 options? Thanks in advance...

Comment: IMHO, you asking the wrong question. As you write _"Because on the web there is some problems I see that `async` call in the `Hub` may cause not being able to connect to the hub sometimes."_, you should ask how to fix that issue. And if the answer to that is to not use `async`, then that is how it needs to be.

Comment: @LGSon Ok, I removed that part from my question. Can I get your opinion now?

Comment: Asking for opinions is ["off-topic"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) at SO.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `async` if you need `await` inside method. `async` is a marker for compiler to generate async state machine.

`should I use async`- use if you need to await.

If you don't need to `await` just return task itself without `async`. In that case you can avoid creation of state machine.

Also please read [Async/Await FAQ](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/asyncawait-faq/) from Stephen Toub:

> When you mark a method with the “async” keyword, you’re really telling
>   the compiler two things:
>
> 1. You’re telling the compiler that you want to be able to use the
>      “await” keyword inside the method (you can use the await keyword if
>      and only if the method or lambda it’s in is marked as async). In doing
>      so, you’re telling the compiler to compile the method using a state
>      machine, such that the method will be able to suspend and then resume
>      asynchronously at await points.
> 2. You’re telling the compiler to “lift”
>      the result of the method or any exceptions that may occur into the
>      return type. For a method that returns Task or Task, this
>      means that any returned value or exception that goes unhandled within
>      the method is stored into the result task. For a method that returns
>      void, this means that any exceptions are propagated to the caller’s
>      context via whatever “SynchronizationContext” was current at the time
>      of the method’s initial invocation.

Comment: Thnaks for reply. I think you describe to convert a method to async method. But I need to know which one I should use. async or non-async in Hub methods. Any why?

Comment: @hexadecimal Main idea here is you should return `Task` to support asynchronous execution all the way. If you need the result of task in method you should add both `async` and `await`. There is no any restriction.

Comment: Thnaks a lot, voted up. Could ou pls have a look at Update 1? When I convert this method to async I encounter Since 'HubBase.OnConnected()' is an async method that returns 'Task', a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression. Did you intend to return 'Task<T>' error. I tried to use Task<T> etc. in order to define return type but not fixed. any idea?

Comment: @hexadecimal `await base.OnConnected();`

Comment: One important question: When I am converting my methods I see that some class does not have async methods of the related calls.

Comment: For example, in the OnConnected() method I use await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, "SignalR Users");. BUT there is no AddToGroupAsync method in the IGroupManager. There is sync method Add in this interface. So, I can use this sync method of this interface, or use AddToGroup method that I defined in Hub. Which one is better? I am not sure if it is a good idea to use sync in asyncron method. But if I use the IGroupManager interface I do not need to define extra methods (AddToGroup, etc) in my Hub class. What do you think?

Comment: This is caused by using `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;` instead of signalr's core library. Most of the methods are sync (also OnConnected()). Any idea?

Comment: @hexadecimal What do you mean here `BUT there is no AddToGroupAsync method in the IGroupManager`? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.igroupmanager?view=aspnetcore-2.2 `AddToGroupAsync(String, String, CancellationToken)`

Comment: I mean that I do not use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR` and use `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR` and there is no AddToGroupAsync method in it. So, I used Add method that is sync. Sİmilarly for OnConnected() method, there is no async version of it in `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR`. In this case should I all use the sync version of them and call them via await in my Hub methods that I convert to async as shown Update 2? Could you pls have a look at 4 issue in the update and clarify me about your opinions? Thanks

Comment: @hexadecimal You don't understand concept `async-await-task`. You should `1.` read async-await faq and understand the difference between async and sync pipeline `2.` you can't await something which is not `Task/ValueTask` (you actually can create custom awaitable but it's another story). So in your update 2: remove all await and async (because you don't need to await synchronous methods) and return `Task.CompletedTask`.

Comment: Thanks but I read the article and have idea about async. But here I cannot use async methods as there is no async version in the Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR library and for this reason I have two ways: **1)** I can continue to use async methods in my Hub class and call the sync version of `Groups.Add()` and `base.OnConnected()` methods as it seen on Update2. **2)** I can convert these hub methods (OnConnected(), OnDisconnected(), AddToGroup(), SendMessage(), etc) to sync completely (in that case I do not benefit of sync methods).

Answer (score 0):

You should use **Async** methods with `await` and `return Task`.

Asynchrony is viral so you should avoid `async void`.

Bad:

```
public async void MethodAsync()
{
    var result = await SendAsync();
    DoSomething(result);
}
```

Good:

```
public async Task MethodAsync()
{
    var result = await SendAsync();
    DoSomething(result);
}
```

There are some awesome async guidelines by @davidfowl [here](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#asynchronous-programming).

**Update**: remove the `return`:

```
public override async Task OnConnected()
{        
    await AddToGroup("stockGroup");

    string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
    _connections.Add(name, Context.ConnectionId);
    await base.OnConnected();
}
```

Comment: Could ou pls have a look at Update 1? When I convert this method to async I encounter *Since 'HubBase.OnConnected()' is an async method that returns 'Task', a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression. Did you intend to return 'Task<T>'* error. I tried to use Task<T> etc. in order to define return type but not fixed. any idea?

Comment: Just return the Task and use the await. this method doesn't required Task<T>

Comment: Yes, I think so but still the same error and if I just leave return alone the error has gone (*"return keyword must not be followed by an object expression"*). However I need to return base.OnConnected(). Any idea?

Comment: public override async Task OnConnected()
{        
    await AddToGroup("stockGroup");

    string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
    _connections.Add(name, Context.ConnectionId);
    base.OnConnected();
}

Comment: Many thanks for your help for both you and @mtkachenko. `await base.OnConnected();` fixed the problem (also added as mtkachenko said). As mtkachenko has post first, I marked his answer :) But of course voted up both of your questions. Regards...

Comment: One important question: When I am converting my methods I see that some class does not have async methods of the related calls.

Comment: For example, in the `OnConnected()` method I use  `await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, "SignalR Users");`. BUT there is no AddToGroupAsync method in the `IGroupManager`. There is sync method Add in this interface. So, I can use this sync method of this interface, or use `AddToGroup` method that I defined in Hub. Which one is better? I am not sure if it is a good idea to use sync in asyncron method. But if I use the IGroupManager interface I do not need to define extra methods (AddToGroup, etc) in my Hub class.  What do you think?

Comment: This is caused by using `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;` instead of signalr's core library. Most of the methods are sync (also OnConnected()). Any idea?

Comment: Could you pls have a look at my last 3 comments and Update 2 in my question? Many thnaks again...